# How to request oauth2 token using Postman in spring oauth2 application?

Tags: spring-boot, curl, spring-security, postman, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to repeat following tutorial:
[Spring Boot and OAuth2](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/)

I stuck on the step [How to Get an Access Token](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_how_to_get_an_access_token)

I don't know how to use curl but I know postman and try to execute request like in the tutorial using the postman.
**tutorial version:**

```
$ curl acme:acmesecret@localhost:8080/oauth/token -d grant_type=client_credentials
```

and **my version:**

[image]

Please help to correct my request

Answer (score 0):

It works if to add user/password in the url like this:

```
acme:acmesecret@localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials
```

Answer (score 0):

client_credentials - it means clientId and secret.

1. Please click on the "Authorization" tab and select "Basic Auth"
2. Put your clientId and secret
3. drop user and password parameters from headers
4. profit